# In Google Cloud, Can we make a VM preemptable after it has been created?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a VM with GPU and have been using it since then.

is it possible to make this VM preemptable by changing it configuration now?

In Edit config, I see preemptability as Off, but it is grayed out and not letting me change it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

According to the google documentation, [these are the properties](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/update-instance-properties#updatable-properties) you can change after creating a VM. As you'll notice, you can not change the preemptive property of an instance.

However, a possibility would be to snapshot your current disk

```
gcloud compute disks snapshot DISK_NAME \
    --snapshot-names=SNAPSHOT_NAME
    --storage-location STORAGE_LOCATION
```

And spin up a new instance using the snapshot of the former

```
gcloud compute instances create VM_NAME \
    --source-snapshot=BOOT_SNAPSHOT_NAME \
    --boot-disk-size=BOOT_DISK_SIZE \
    --boot-disk-type=BOOT_DISK_TYPE \
    --boot-disk-device-name=BOOT_DISK_NAME
```

Full GCP Documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#restore_boot_snapshot